# Во всём её разнообразии? Верно согласование?

Tags: синтаксис, согласование, выбор-варианта

«Во всём его разнообразии» или «Во всей её разнообразии» (ну это, как по мне, дичь)? Верен первый вариант?

Comment: :)  Хоть его, хоть ее, будет *во всём разнообразии*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предложения нет. Придумаем, дичь встроим. Верен шапочный вариант.
*Мы смогли рассмотреть дичь **во всём её** разнообразии.*

Разбираем:
смогли рассмотреть (в чём? П. п.) в разнообразии;
в разнообразии (каком? П. п.) во всём;
в разнообразии (чьём? П. п.) её [дичи].

Притяжательное местоимение ***её*** (или *его*, или *их*) — выбирается в зависимости от рода или числа заменяемого существительного (дичь — ж. р.).

Можно ведь выбрать маршрут, который был бы им по силам, но вместе с тем достаточно сложным и интересным, чтобы дети смогли увидеть **пустыню** во всем **ее** разнообразии, почувствовать ее дыхание. [Н. Зимин. Читатель в пути. Семейный портрет на фоне пустыни // «Вокруг света», 1997]

Перед глазами проносятся милые сердцу картины заснеженной **тайги** во всем **ее** разнообразии. [Б. И. Вронский. Дневник (1961)]

Теоретически местоимение "её" можно вообще опустить без потери смысла.

Я присоединялся к разным группам, но долго не задерживался. Хотелось послушать **толпу** во всем разнообразии. Выкликали лозунги. [Сергей Юрский. Вспышки. Заключительная глава книги // «Октябрь», 2001]

Comment: Всё её (чьё?) разнообразие; во всём её (чьём?) разнообразии. Sharon, Вы именно это имели в виду? Н-да... Похоже, что бес попутал, вкупе с родительным падежом. Спасибо.

Comment: @Sharon, гляньте-посмотрите, теперь — вроде бы всё по-человечески.